# Unable to install express using npm in windows 10

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install

I have tried a number of times to install express using npm. The attached image shows the nodejs npm install express `SyntaxError`

[image]

I have manually copied the npmrc file into AppData with the same results.

I have changed my PATH to

```
C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

I can not get express to install.

Comment: what version of nodejs , and npm are you running ?

Comment: Have you tried updating npm with npm? `npm install -g npm`

Comment: Instead of changing your path, use the nodejs command prompt from your start menu.